# how to fix app stopping in android studio emulator?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

D/19.0.56 (100700-262933554):3)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
        at libcore.io.Linux.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.android_getaddrinfo(BlockGuardOs.java:172)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:137)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:105) 
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1154) 
        at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:218) 
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket.(SSLSocket.java:904) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.AbstractConscryptSocket.(AbstractConscryptSocket.java:37) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptSocketBase.(ConscryptSocketBase.java:93) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:40) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:129) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.Java8FileDescriptorSocket.(Java8FileDescriptorSocket.java:25) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.createFileDescriptorSocket(Platform.java:323) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:103) 
        at avm.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@19056084@19.0.56 (100700-262933554):44) 
        at avo.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@19056084@19.0.56 (100700-262933554):3) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
        at libcore.io.Linux.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method) 
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.android_getaddrinfo(BlockGuardOs.java:172) 
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:137) 
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:105) 
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1154) 
        at java.net.Socket.(Socket.java:218) 
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket.(SSLSocket.java:904) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.AbstractConscryptSocket.(AbstractConscryptSocket.java:37) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptSocketBase.(ConscryptSocketBase.java:93) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:40) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:129) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.Java8FileDescriptorSocket.(Java8FileDescriptorSocket.java:25) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.createFileDescriptorSocket(Platform.java:323) 
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(OpenSSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:103) 
        at avm.d(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@19056084@19.0.56 (100700-262933554):44) 
        at avo.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesc@19056084@19.0.56 (100700-262933554):3) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe4705480: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe4703730)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7898 SIG: 9
Process 7898 terminated.

List item

---

Comment: (No address associated with hostname) means that the endpoint you're trying to hit does not exist or is not available due to lack of internet availability. If you want help fixing this you will need to post the relevant code here

Comment: Thank-you i am new here